# How to filter array using same key value of(preview_url and countries code) and return higher amount of array and unmatch array data will be same

Tags: php, arrays, sorting, multidimensional-array

I have this array i want sorting using same preview_url and same countries code and want result which array have higher amount of value and unmatch array data remain same.
I want result i have add in comment please provide sollution for same i have stuck on this issue from couple of days

Thanks in advance

```
Array
(
    [id] => 377556        
    [amount] => 1.46000
    [preview_url] => https://itunes.apple.com/app/id543186831?mt=8
    [countries] => Array
        (
            [US] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 840
                    [code] => US
                    [name] => united states
                    [regions] => Array
                        (
                        )
                )
        )
)
Array
(
    [id] => 377557        
    [amount] => 2.46000
    [preview_url] => https://itunes.apple.com/app/id543186831?mt=8
    [countries] => Array
        (
            [US] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 840
                    [code] => US
                    [name] => united states                        
                )
            [UK] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 841
                    [code] => UK
                    [name] => united kingdom
                )    
        )
)
```

Comment: i want this result Array
(
    [id] => 377557  [amount] => 2.46000 [preview_url] => https://itunes.apple.com/app/id543186831?mt=8[countries] => Array
        (            [US] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 840  [code] => US [name] => united states)
            [UK] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 841
                    [code] => UK
                    [name] => united kingdom
                    [regions] => Array
                        (
                        )
                )    
        )
)

Answer (score 0):

You can sort it by using **usort**.

```
usort($array, function($a, $b) {
     return $a['amount'] < $b['amount'];
});
```

[For details refer this great answer by christian. Kudos](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2699159/4419992)

**Happy Coding.**

Comment: thanks for answering but i have to compare with preview_url and countrie code so how can i compare?

Comment: how can i comapare for preview url and countri code?

Comment: you want to sort on basis of amount or preview url ?

Comment: i want to sort with both previewurl and country with higher amount value

Comment: can you please mention priority of order in which you want to sort.
clear what you want to achieve. First sort on basis of amount, then on preview url, am I right ? country is an array, on what key of country you want to sort ?

Comment: i want this result Array ( [id] => 377557 [amount] => 2.46000 [preview_url] => itunes.apple.com/app/id543186831?mt=8[countries] => Array ( [US] => Array ( [id] => 840 [code] => US [name] => united states) [UK] => Array ( [id] => 841 [code] => UK [name] => united kingdom [regions] => Array ( ) ) ) )

Comment: if preview_url and countri code is same then i want to display array who has  higher amount value

Comment: is there any update on my question i am still not getting proper sollution for same

Answer (score 0):

> You have to use [multisort](http://php.net/array_multisort)

```
$mylist = array(
array('ID' => 1, 'title' => 'Boring Meeting', 'event_type' => 'meeting'),
array('ID' => 2, 'title' => 'Find My Stapler', 'event_type' => 'meeting'),
array('ID' => 3, 'title' => 'Mario Party', 'event_type' => 'party'),
array('ID' => 4, 'title' => 'Duct Tape Party', 'event_type' => 'party')
);
# get a list of sort columns and their data to pass to array_multisort
$sort = array();
foreach($mylist as $k=>$v) {
$sort['title'][$k] = $v['title'];
$sort['event_type'][$k] = $v['event_type'];
}
# sort by event_type desc and then title asc
array_multisort($sort['event_type'], SORT_DESC, $sort['title'], SORT_ASC,$mylist);
$mylist = array(
array('ID' => 1, 'title' => 'Boring Meeting', 'event_type' => 'meeting'),
array('ID' => 2, 'title' => 'Find My Stapler', 'event_type' => 'meeting'),
array('ID' => 3, 'title' => 'Mario Party', 'event_type' => 'party'),
array('ID' => 4, 'title' => 'Duct Tape Party', 'event_type' => 'party')
);
# get a list of sort columns and their data to pass to array_multisort
$sort = array();
foreach($mylist as $k=>$v) {
$sort['title'][$k] = $v['title'];
$sort['event_type'][$k] = $v['event_type'];
}
# sort by event_type desc and then title asc
array_multisort($sort['event_type'], SORT_DESC, $sort['title'], SORT_ASC,$mylist);
```

> now my array will

```
array (
0 => 
array (
'ID' => 4,
'title' => 'Duct Tape Party',
'event_type' => 'party',
),
1 => 
array (
'ID' => 3,
'title' => 'Mario Party',
'event_type' => 'party',
),
2 => 
array (
'ID' => 1,
'title' => 'Boring Meeting',
'event_type' => 'meeting',
),
3 => 
array (
'ID' => 2,
'title' => 'Find My Stapler',
'event_type' => 'meeting',
),
)
```

Comment: This is not my sollution

Comment: can you explain in detail?

Comment: if preview_url and countri code is same then i want to display array who has higher amount value

Comment: i want this result Array ( [id] => 377557 [amount] => 2.46000 [preview_url] => itunes.apple.com/app/id543186831?mt=8[countries] => Array ( [US] => Array ( [id] => 840 [code] => US [name] => united states) [UK] => Array ( [id] => 841 [code] => UK [name] => united kingdom [regions] => Array ( ) ) ) )

Comment: First you have to sort your inner array using foreach..and then you can easily sort your outer erray using sort function [plz visit here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-multisort.php) and you have to use some good logic

Comment: but which method i have to use for sorting (preview_url and countries code ) and then i have to select higher amount of array

Comment: Bro as per your requirements take your any one array and sort it using sort function after it sort another array

Comment: can you code what you want to say?

Comment: not now but i will do it when i will free. i will also learn something new from this

Comment: ok please update me when you get time and thanks in advance ...!!

Comment: Sure i will update asap

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/139635/discussion-between-er-nilay-parekh-and-jagdish-chaudhary).